# Command to switch the region on aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

What is the command to switch the region on aws cli. I want to switch to another region where my lambdas are present
I have tried these commands but they doesn't work

```
aws --region <region_name>
aws set region <region_name>
aws configure region <region_name>
aws lambda .... --region <region_name>
```

Comment: try passing the `--region` variable before `lambda`. Like this: `aws --region us-east-1 lambda ...`.

Answer (score 6):

You can set the `AWS_REGION` environment variable so that the AWS CLI would use it in the subsequent calls:

```bash
export AWS_REGION=us-east-1
```

Then if you use

```
aws lambda ...
```

command it would be executed in that region.

Alternatively, if you want this change to be persisted you can change your `~/.aws/credentials` file and set the region there.

Answer (score 4):

You can set/switch the AWS region in AWS CLI using the `aws configure set` command. Below is the command to set/switch region.

```
aws configure set region <region_name>
```

and the attached image has an example of my AWS CLI configuration after switching the region.

[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvpte.png)

Reference - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configure/set.html

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell `--region <region>` should do the job. In most of the cases I use the `region` parameter as a part of my profile. If it doesn't work in your case, check the environment variable.

Reference: [Command line options - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-options.html)

Answer (score 2):

AWS cli provides the way to set region at anytime you wish. You can use following command to set the region

`aws configure --region <region>`

For example:

`aws configure --region us-east-2`

After this cli will ask you ID and Secret, You can see it will come with existing creds just hit enter and move ahead. If it ask for region give the new region and hit enter, That's it! You are good to go ahead.